# Linear Program Modelling Coinset pay amount $k$

Tags: linear-programming, problem-solving

You are given a coinset ov values **c1,...,cn** and a target value of **k** you need to pay. For each **i** element *{1,...,n}* let ni be the number of coins of value **ci** in your wallet. You want to pay (or overpay) the target value **k** such that the number of coins in your wallet (after the change has been paid) is minimized.
You can assume that the change is returned in a minimum number of coins.
Contrusct an ILP that sloves the problem. Explain the meaning of all the variables.

I have no glue.... Here is my "try":

Variable: x - for the number of coins in my wallet (coinset c1,...,n)
          c - the value of the Sum of the Coins

Objective Function:

```
      min the Sum of the coins in my wallet: also min x
```

Constraints:

```
      s.t.      c <= k
```

I think this is not complete and not right......

Comment: Are the coins $c_1, \dots, c_n$ all the coins that exist in this "universe"? If not, we have incomplete information to solve the problem.

Comment: Also the variable $n$ is being used for both the number of coin types and the number of each coin you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the question uses the variable $n$ to represent both the number of coin types and the number of each coin you have. This is confusing to say the least, so let's say you have $m_i$ coins of value $c_i$ to begin with, where $i$ ranges from $1, \dots, n$. Secondly, I'm assuming one can neglect the change returned; the question is unclear in this regard.

Instead of having one variable $x$ representing the total amount, let's have variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ where $x_i$ is the number of coins of value $c_i$ that you spend. Therefore, your objective function is the following:

$$\min m_1 + \dots + m_n - x_1 - \dots - x_n$$

Now, consider the constraints. We need the value of the coins we spend to equal or exceed $k$:

$$c_1x_1+\dots+c_nx_n\geq k$$

We cannot spend more coins than we have:

$$x_1\leq m_1$$

$$\vdots$$

$$x_n\leq m_n$$

We must spend a nonnegative number of coins:

$$x_1\geq0$$

$$\vdots$$

$$x_n\geq0$$

Finally, all variables are integers:

$$x_1, \dots, x_n\text{ integer}$$